# Temparory Table update

Tags: mysql

I âm creating some temporary table in mysql 
updating this table but get error

```
`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (id varchar(50), name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (1, 'LF/2019/0001');
SELECT name FROM test;
UPDATE test SET name = (SELECT name FROM test ORDER BY id DESC) + 1 WHERE id = 1;`
```

> ```
> Error show : 
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1137 - Can't reopen table: 'test'
> ```

Please help,
Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So don't use a temporary table

Comment: I want update table with +1 value

Comment: You want to increment some portion of the name field by 1?

Comment: @Strawberry : Ok I used normal table and remove temporary table but also gating same error

Comment: @P.Salmon : yes

Comment: Ok . Step 1 is to write a SELECT query that returns both test and the desired value

Comment: Hi Saintsve 
First of all you are trying to update a string with integer value

Comment: @Ajay : Please help how to update

Comment: I still don't get it , what did you hope to achieve with the order by, BTW I am voting to close because question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update that particular column for once then you can use following script

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (id varchar(50), name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (1, 'LF/2019/0001');
SELECT name FROM test;
UPDATE test SET name = concat('LF/2019/000',cast((cast(SELECT substring(name,9) FROM test ORDER BY id DESC) as unsigned integer) + 1) as char) WHERE id = '1';

drop table test
```